# if there is no "not only", is it idiomatic to say "but also"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=57)

> It includes how to collect your data, how to label your data, how to
>   choose an architecture, but also how to design a proper loss function
>   to optimize.

there is no "not only", is it idiomatic to say "but also"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be argued either way. On one hand, it sounds like he is just listing a series of features, which would normally be a comma-separated list and then the final feature linked with "and":

> It includes how to collect your data, how to label your data, how to choose an architecture, *and* how to design a proper loss function to optimize.

As you state, if his intention was to *contrast* the first three features with the final one it would have made more sense to lead with "*not only*". However, in *spoken*, extemperaneous speech, we don't always know how a sentence is going to end when we begin it. It may be that the lecturer felt the last feature in his list *was* something contrasting to the others but didn't think to set that up from the beginning?